# Cookie value returns null when accessed from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to save some data on cookies. I have this in my controller.

```
Question[] qns = new.Question[0]; 
for(int i=0;i<qns.Length;i++)
{
HttpCookie c1 = new.HttpCookie("QuestionID" + i, qns[i].QuestionID.ToString ());
c1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(c1);
}
```

and this in my view

```
@Html.Label(Request.Cookies["QuestionID0"].Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

I get a Null reference exception at the view. I have also tried Response.Cookies but it doesn't work. Would you help me plelase?

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Cookies` and `Request.Cookies` are two different collections of cookies. The `Request.Cookies` is what is sent by the browser to your application. The `Response.Cookies` are the cookies you want to add or update on your browser.

In your controller action you are updating the `Response.Cookies` collection, but in the view you are attempting to read the cookies from the `Request.Cookies` collection.

However, I would never directly access cookies in the view. I would add the values to the model that I pass to the view and get the data from there. I would say that the only source of data that the view should use is the Model (and maybe in the `ViewBag`, but I try and avoid that)

Comment: What shall I do then for the request not to return null?

Comment: I repeat the advice in my last paragraph - Do not try and access the cookies in the view. Put the values you want to render in the view into the model and render from there.